# Introductory text on amenability

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, textbook-recommendation, amenability

I am looking for a book that covers amenability rigorously. 
Preferably a book aimed at beginners.

Comment: Depending on what you want, Davidson's *C$^*$-algebras by example* or Wagon's *The Banach-Tarski Paradox*.

Comment: Appendix G on amenability of the book [Kazhdan's Property (T)](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/bachir.bekka/KazhdanTotal.pdf) by Bekka, de la Harpe, Valette.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the book [Amenability](https://www.ams.org/books/surv/029/) by Alan.t. Paterson. It contains everything about amenability of groups till the publication year 1988. But a newest one is [Lectures on Amenability](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540428527) by Volker. Runde . It's main theme is about amenability of Banch Algebras.